# add custom field to admin > permission > add user

Tags: admin

i want to add custom field to admin permission add user.

Via module / observer pls guide me how can i do it

Comment: can you provide a use case?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a rewrite for the tabs block to add a new tab:

```
<blocks>
    <your_module>
        <class>Your_Module_Block</class>
    </your_module>

    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <permissions_user_edit_tabs>Your_Module_Block_Block_Adminhtml_Crm_Permissions_User_Edit_Tabs</permissions_user_edit_tabs>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

After that you can easily add the new tab in _beforeToHtml()

```
class Your_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Crm_Permissions_User_Edit_Tabs
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Tabs
{
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->addTabAfter('store_section', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('New Tab Title'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('New Tab Title'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('your_module/adminhtml_crm_permissions_user_edit_tab_newtab', 'user.stores.form')->toHtml(),
        ), 'roles_section');
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

After that, you can add two observers, to handle your data after load, before save:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <admin_user_load_after>
            <observers>
                <your_module>
                    <class>your_module/observer</class>
                    <method>adminUserLoadAfter</method>
                </your_module>
            </observers>
        </admin_user_load_after>
        <admin_user_save_before>
            <observers>
                <your_module>
                    <class>your_module/observer</class>
                    <method>adminUserSaveBefore</method>
                </your_module>
            </observers>
        </admin_user_save_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: wow... nice. Would give you a +2 if possible

Comment: what will be path of this file app/code/local/Your/Module ??

Comment: Yes! Or community/Your/Module.